# VB.NET value type of 'bitmap' cannot be converted to 'string'

Tags: vb.net

I'm storing image to Properties>Resource but when i call it in my code i get the error

> value type of 'bitmap' cannot be converted to 'string'

```
           oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(My.Resources.123_LOGO,
           Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 0, 0, 940, 120)
```

What do you think the problem is?
I already this one and its not working

```
Dim imge As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(700, 1500)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imge)
 oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(g,
               Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 0, 0, 940, 120)
```

Comment: `Shapes.AddPicture()` expects the path of a File (a string). You're passing a Bitmap.

Comment: How do i do that? I already try this ` Dim Image As String = Convert.ToString(My.Resources.Capture)` and I'm having a hard time

Comment: why dont you use `imge.save("temp.bmp")` to save the bitmap and then use `Shapes.AddPicture("temp.bmp")` to read it as file, then remove `temp.bmp`

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do in a Word document application.

```
        fName = "rKeyPoints32"
        img = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(fName)
        img.Save(ThisAddIn.LGPUserTempDir & fName & ".png")
        wApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(ThisAddIn.LGPUserTempDir & fName & ".png")
        Kill(ThisAddIn.LGPUserTempDir & fName)
        img = Nothing
```